# Visual Studio 2012 - Keeping the search box open when switching between files

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Not a fan of the "updated" search box in VS 2012. When I perform a search, I'd like to keep that search box visible as I'm clicking through my file tab well. Right now, it seems like the search box can only be visible for one file at a time.

For example, I'm have 2 files open. I search for the word "eyepatch" in the current file. I next want to perform this same search on the next file. But when click on the next file, the search box disappears and I have to do a `ctrl + f` and type "eyepatch" again.

Anyone know how to make this easier?

Answer (score -1):

Hit F3 (Find Next).  It keeps the search text from the previous search upon next invocation.

Answer (score -1):

Select [All Open Documents] from the drop down menu at the bottom of the Search Box